# How to get the item attribute of an xml file, when the the number of items within a tag is always changing

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, feed

I have this bit of xml code below and I'm trying to get the value of all of the "result value" attributes within the results tag. The thing is...this is going to be a live feed, so there may be 1,2 or 3 result items within that tag.

Do I need to do some sort of count to see how many items are within the results tag?

```
<Match ct="0" id="771597" LastPeriod="2 HF" LeagueCode="19984" LeagueSort="1" LeagueType="LEAGUE" startTime="15:00" status="2 HF" statustype="live" type="2" visible="1">
    <Home id="11676" name="Manchester City" standing="1"/>
    <Away id="10826" name="Newcastle United" standing="3"/>
    <Results>
        <Result id="1" name="CURRENT" value="1-1"/>
        <Result id="2" name="FT" value="1-1"/>
        <Result id="3" name="HT" value="1-0"/>
    </Results>
    <Information>
        <league id="19984">Premier League</league>
        <note/>
        <bitarray/>
        <timestamp/>
    </Information>
</Match>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SimpleXML

Just loop through the results with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to grab each `value` and `name` attribute, this will work with a variable number of results.

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/8OjsJETx)**

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($obj->Results->Result as $result)
{
    echo $result->attributes()->name . ': ' . $result->attributes()->value . "\n";
}
```

**Outputs**

> CURRENT: 1-1
>   FT: 1-1
>   HT: 1-0

If you have a root node such as `Matches` with multiple `Match` under it then you would use a nested `foreach` like so:

```
foreach($obj->Match as $match)
{
    foreach($match->Results->Result as $result)
    {
        echo $result->attributes()->name . ': ' . $result->attributes()->value . "\n";
    }
}
```

---

### DOMDocument

To do the same using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of SimpleXML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('Match') as $match)
{
    foreach($match->getElementsByTagName('Result') as $result)
    {
        echo $result->getAttribute('name') . ': ' . $result->getAttribute('value') . "\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs the same as the SimpleXML method.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm using dom though. Would this still work if I had a feed with multiple "match" tags

Comment: See my edit - for multiple matches you can use a nested foreach

Comment: thanks again, do you know how I would do this use dom rather than simplexml, as the rest of my code uses dom?

Comment: because with dom I have to call an item number which only returns one value

Comment: by dom do you mean the DOMDocument class?

Comment: yes: such as $dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom ->load('string.xml');